# systemd-resolved keeps multiple copies of cache?

Tags: cache, systemd-resolved

I put `systemd-resolved` into debug mode trying to troubleshoot high number of DNS queries from this machine (`tcfe01`). It seems `systemd-resolved` is keeping multiple copies of cache, one for global scope (`*/*`) and another for particular network device (`eno1/*`). From the logs it seems only global scope (`*/*`) gets cached but not (`eno1/*`). For first query we see `Cache miss` for both scopes, but for subsequent queries we get `Positive cache hit` for global scope, but `Cache miss` again for device scope and we end up hitting the DNS server every single time.

This defeats the whole purpose of having the cache, not only hurting the performance on local machine (`tcfe01`) but also unnecessarily hammering the DNS server. Any insight into this behavior would be very helpful.

```
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Got DNS stub UDP query packet for id 14184
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Looking up RR for google.com IN A.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Switching to DNS server 192.168.10.25 for interface eno1.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Switching to system DNS server 192.168.10.25.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Cache miss for google.com IN A
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Transaction 48281 for <google.com IN A> scope dns on */*.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 48281.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Using DNS server 192.168.10.25 for transaction 48281.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Sending query packet with id 48281.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Cache miss for google.com IN A
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Transaction 1213 for <google.com IN A> scope dns on eno1/*.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 1213.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Using DNS server 192.168.10.25 for transaction 1213.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Sending query packet with id 1213.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Processing query...
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Processing incoming packet on transaction 48281. (rcode=SUCCESS)
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Verified we get a response at feature level UDP+EDNS0 from DNS server 192.168.10.25.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Added positive unauthenticated cache entry for google.com IN A 299s on */INET/192.168.10.25
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Transaction 48281 for <google.com IN A> on scope dns on */* now complete with <success> from network (unsigned).
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Freeing transaction 1213.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Sending response packet with id 14184 on interface 1/AF_INET.
Apr 23 16:45:34 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Freeing transaction 48281.


Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Got DNS stub UDP query packet for id 50679
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Looking up RR for google.com IN A.
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Positive cache hit for google.com IN A
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Transaction 51371 for <google.com IN A> on scope dns on */* now complete with <success> from cache (unsigned).
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Cache miss for google.com IN A
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Transaction 16504 for <google.com IN A> scope dns on eno1/*.
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 16504.
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Using DNS server 192.168.10.25 for transaction 16504.
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Sending query packet with id 16504.
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Freeing transaction 51371.
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Freeing transaction 16504.
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Sending response packet with id 50679 on interface 1/AF_INET.
Apr 23 16:45:45 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Processing query...


Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Got DNS stub UDP query packet for id 50950
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Looking up RR for google.com IN A.
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Positive cache hit for google.com IN A
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Transaction 27482 for <google.com IN A> on scope dns on */* now complete with <success> from cache (unsigned).
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Cache miss for google.com IN A
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Transaction 24663 for <google.com IN A> scope dns on eno1/*.
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 24663.
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Using DNS server 192.168.10.25 for transaction 24663.
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Sending query packet with id 24663.
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Freeing transaction 27482.
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Freeing transaction 24663.
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Sending response packet with id 50950 on interface 1/AF_INET.
Apr 23 16:45:48 tcfe01 systemd-resolved[26041]: Processing query...
```

Comment: you need to [configure](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#Protocols%20and%20Routing) your link as a route-only domain (~.)

Comment: Thanks @bac0n, following your lead I could fix the issue. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I added an entry `Domains=~.` to the file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and restarted _systemd_resolved.service_. Now only the global DNS is being used for DNS lookups.

Comment: ...and if you put it on a link, you get that result on the link

Comment: @bac0n I could not find the exact location where I could put it just for the link. I guess it would be _systemd-networkd_ setting?

Comment: [systemd.network](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#Domains=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question here as at least the problem I was facing is now resolved. Thanks @bac0n for pointing me in right direction. So `systemd-resolve --status` showed DNS servers configured for global as well for per-link settings. This was causing every query to be resolved twice. I configured global DNS to be the final DNS by adding entry `Domains=~.` to file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and restarting *systemd-resolved.service*.

As @bac0n mentioned, I could have done the same for my specific link through *systemd-network* settings. Since I am using netplan and am not configuring *systemd-network* directly I believe I have to use netplan for these settings. And I could not easily find that option for netplan. So I am leaving it at that for now.